# What does H in PC3-10700H memory stand for?

Tags: memory, ddr3

I have two Corsair RAMs 4GB DDR3 Desktop memory. CPU-Z reports one as PC3-10700 & other as PC3-10700H. See the attached screenshot.

What does H in PC3-10700H stand for and is there any difference between the two? The part number for both sticks is same. I have searched the internet but could not get any relevant references.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I believe the H stands for the timing of the RAM module, specifically the timing 9-9-9-9.

I do not believe there is likely any significant difference between the two modules, especially as the part number is the same.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM

Comment: People seem to agree: http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2097605/ddr3-1600mhz-showing-pc3-10700h.html

Answer (score 0):

That H generally means that there is an XMP/DOCP profile available for the RAM. It will default to 667MHz, but can likely be bumped up to 800MHz.